# C++ non const rvalue parameter workaround

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I have some Stream classes which provide basic IO.
I want to be able to write code like this:

```
Image img = Image(StreamReader("filepath"));
```

Unfortunately, according to the standard, it seems to be illegal to bind rvalue references to non const lvalue references, like the Image ctor's argument.

I cannot make the argument a const reference because Streams will need to update their state, e.g. the current streamposition.

Making these Stream attributes mutable or const casting them seems like bad design to me, as these states have noticable effects for the user.

What options do I have to make this work, preferrably without having two nearly identical constructors for every 'Image-like' class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: forwarding reference?

Comment: You mention two nearly identical constructors. What does your other constructor look like?

Comment: I meant not having one constructor taking lvalue and one taking rvalue.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood the question. TBH I would just add two constructors rather than mess around with perfect forwarding. You can implement the `StreamReader&&` overload by calling the `StreamReader&` overload. KISS.

Comment: As it seems you consume `StreamReader`, provide only constructor taking `StreamReader&&` might have sense (and so force user to use `std::move` when it is not already a temporary).

Comment: I agree that the template stuff is quite complex for what i want here. Also it'll require the ctors to be implemented in the header file, which I would rather avoid. As I'm not an expert in the language I hoped there would be a simple way to do this. (Btw in MSVC this just works as is because their compiler provides non const && as a non standard extension). That's also the root of the problem, as I have unknowingly relied on this behaviour, making the amount of code to change quite substantial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What options do I have to make this work, preferrably without having two nearly identical constructors for every 'Image-like' class?

You want [**perfect forwarding**](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/). It will allow you to define a single function that accepts both `const&` and `&&`:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, Image>>>
Image::Image(T&& x)
{//          ^^^ 
 //          "forwarding reference"

    doSomething(std::forward<T>(x));
 //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //             keep forwarding either as an rvalue reference or lvalue
 //             reference depending on the original value category of `x`
}
```

Usage:

```
Image a{StreamReader("filepath")}; // rvalue

const StreamReader s("filepath");
Image b{s}; // const lvalue

StreamReader s2("filepath");
Image c{s2}; // lvalue
```

---

If you want to prevent `const&` from being accepted, you can either `delete` that particular overload, or add it to the `enable_if_t` clause:

- `Image(const StreamReader&) = delete;`

  *(Assumes that the type will always be `StreamReader`).*
- `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, Image>>`

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be nearly it. But I dont want to pass const& but &. 
(Even an lvalue stream would change its file position when passed.) Is that possible with this?

Comment: @ChrisB: yes, it accepts everything. Updated my example.

Comment: Thank you very much! can i somehow prevent const& from being accepted?

Comment: @ChrisB: sure this, just add it to the `enable_if_t` clause. Updating the answer...

Comment: @ChrisB: done. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Almost there! Thank you for your patience with me:).
1. Shouldn't  it be is_same<..., StreamReader>?
2. Im pretty sure is_same fails on subclasses, can we fix this somehow?

Comment: @ChrisB: no, I'm trying to prevent the perfect-forwarding-constructor from hijacking `Image(const Image&)` and `Image(Image&&)`, which might be implicitly generated. The `is_same` is doing that.

Comment: Aahh thanks I think I can make this work . Thanks for your help!